# Error while adding an product to an opportunity

Tags: opportunity, pricebook, product

When user tries to Add an Product to the opportunity record ,it throws an

```
Error as : Currency null is not supported by this org.
```

The price book which user is selecting is "Standard Price Book" .

At OWD level the pricebook has "NO ACCESS" .

At pricebook created an Pricebook name as "Standard Price Book" ,Active field is checked but unable to check the Isstandardprice field.Created a role access.But still Unable to Add products to opportunity record .

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: do you have multi currency enabled for your org?

Comment: @Himanshu:i think yes ,but not sure...As far as i see we USE USD the most.

Comment: Is it through UI or code?

Comment: @Kaushik Ray :It is UI.

Comment: This is most probably because of multi currency, make sure to check field level security of Currency field for the logged in user.